# JSON array parsing in PHP

Tags: php, json, matomo

please help me how to parse following JSON in PHP.

I got following JSON using PIWIK reporting api. How do I get PageTitle from following json in PHP. I tried following code for JSON parsing.

```
$json = '[
{
    "idSite": "1",
    "idVisit": "84",
    "visitorId": "f08dc1f2a3e1f839",
    "visitorType": "returning",
    "visitorTypeIcon": "plugins/Live/images/returningVisitor.gif",
    "visitConverted": "0",
    "visitConvertedIcon": null,
    "visitEcommerceStatus": "none",
    "visitEcommerceStatusIcon": null,
    "searches": "0",
    "events": "4",
    "actions": "9",
    "actionDetails": [
        {
            "type": "action",
            "url": "http://mywwebsiteurl.com",
            "pageTitle": "PageTitle",
            "pageIdAction": "110"
        }
    ]
}
]';

$visits = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($visits->actionDetails as $data) { 
      echo $data->pageTitle;
}
```

I got following notice

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

How to get pageTitle from above JSON.

Comment: $visits->actionDetails['pageTitle'] should access the data. As you put true as the second parameter it returns an array not a stdClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :-

```
$visits = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($visits[0]["actionDetails"] as $data) { 
      echo $data["pageTitle"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got pageTitle.

Answer (score 0):

You set second attribute to TRUE - so according to the manual. 
"When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays."

Try using the array aproach

```
foreach ($visits['actionDetails'] as $data){
    echo $data['pageTitle'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As [documented in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), and [mentioned by Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694202/json-array-parsing-in-php#comment38291736_24694202), the second parameter of json_decode() controls the return type.  If it is omitted or set to false (the default) then an object is returned.  If it is set to true an array is returned.

Your code, `json_decode($json, true);`, will return an array but you then try to use the array as an object.